# How to retrieve/read an image from MongoDB's GridFS in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, gridfs

```
with cv2.imread("Desktop/foo.jpg") as img:
    b = fs.put(img, filename="foo")
```

I use the above block of code to save an image. The issue is, how do I get it back and read it through some common library like PIL in Python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gridfs.GridFS.find_one`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs/#gridfs.GridFS.find_one) allows to find a file that was saved to GridFS using a filename.

This method returns an instance [`grid_file.GridOut`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridOut) that can be read.

```
file = fs.find_one({'filename': 'foo'})
image = file.read()
```

Comment: I've tried to save this file back as :

outfilename = "img.jpg"
output= open(outfilename,"wb")
output.write(image)

But it does not work. Can you help with this?

Comment: How do you mean that it doesn't work? What's the error?

Comment: Nvm. I forgot to close the file. It's done now. Thanks for your help.